# Glitch drawing 2D textures

Tags: c#, xna, 2d, monogame

I'm having a problem with drawing extra textures. 
This is what the world should look like: red square = player, green parts = dirt.
[image: world in Paint.NET]

And this is how the world looks like:
[image: world ingame]

As you can see, there are some extra textures (they dont have collision or anything they are just drawn on the screen)

Here's my dirt sprite sheet:
[image: dirt sprite sheet]

And here's my drawing code:

```
public void DrawStatics(Block[,] blocks)
{

    spriteBatch.Begin(WorldManager.Instance.currentWorld.camera, SpriteSortMode.Deferred, samplerState: SamplerState.PointClamp);
    foreach (Block block in blocks)
    {
        if (block == null || block.id == BlockID.Air) continue;
        spriteBatch.Draw(texture: block.texture, position: block.position, color: Color.White, sourceRectangle: new Rectangle(block.index * 20, 0, block.index * 20 + 20, 20));
    }
    spriteBatch.End();
}
```

Comment: Are you drawing things multiple times? Like for example the hitbox? I see nothing wrong with your `DrawStatics method` that would cause this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You are not re-drawing the blue background at all; you should re-draw it as often as the foreground.

The following snippet implies some assumptions about your code.

```
public void DrawStatics(Block[,] blocks)
{
    spriteBatch.Begin(
        WorldManager.Instance.currentWorld.camera,
        SpriteSortMode.Deferred,
        samplerState: SamplerState.PointClamp
    );
    foreach (Block block in blocks)
    {
        if (block != null)
        {
            // Not ignoring BlockID.Air
            spriteBatch.Draw(
                texture: block.texture, // There should be a texture for BlockID.Air...
                position: block.position,
                color: Color.White, // ...or a block.color could be saved as a fallback.
                sourceRectangle: new Rectangle(
                    block.index * 20, 0, block.index * 20 + 20, 20)
            );
        }
    }
    spriteBatch.End();
}
```

Note about coding style:

- the `continue` statement can make the code flow harder to follow; its use is often discouraged, and your code is actually shorter without it.
- Long lines of code make the code harder to read.
- I recommend having that `20` in a constant (`const int tileSideInPX = 20;`): it will make it easier to edit at once, it will make your code more readable and it won't affect performance at all.